# Optimizing a Web Page to get it to embed well on Facebook, Embedly, et al

Tags: html, facebook, embed

What code elements do I need to add/modify on a Web page to ensure that it gets embedded properly on a facebook status update?!

See below for an example of what I think is a good embed:

[image]

Some web pages I tried to embed don't appear very well on facebook i.e. when you put their links in a status update. Also, sometimes it gives you a selection of images to choose from?!

Is this purely a `<meta>` tag play, or are there other things I could do to ensure that the web page gets embedded the way I want it to (images and all)?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is meta tags at work. You need to specify Open Graph metadata to define what appears on Facebook. See http://ogp.me/

Comment: Thanks. It appears facebook still does a pretty decent job of by crawling text and images (and providing a selection for users to choose) when the meta-tags you have described are not present. I guess I'll play around with some web page samples and see how it works out.